# Set Theory Equivalence clarification

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

When I read about equivalence $(A=B)$ between two sets I get two definitions:

1. \begin{equation}  
   A \subset B    \\
   B \subset A    \\
   \end{equation}
2. \begin{equation}  
   A \subseteq  B    \\
   B \subseteq  A    \\
   \end{equation}

I feel definition (1) is not correct because in order to become proper subset there must be an element which is not a part of other set. I am ok with definition (2). But in some books I see definition (1). Could you confirm which is correct?

Comment: It might just be laziness; some people use the symbols interchangeably, I've found.

Comment: The second one, because some authors use $\subset$ with the meaning of $\subseteq$. Which has the result of me never using $\subset$, but rather just $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ (or $\subsetneqq$).

Comment: It is worth mentioning, though, that $A=B\leftrightarrow (A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq A)$ is not quite a definition of "$=$", but rather an axiomatic property of the binary relation "$\in$".

Answer (score 5):

Some textbooks use $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$, the 'correct' definition is the second one, but people use the first one just as a notational shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

2 is correct.

We can see this by checking the definition of $⊆$: $$A \subseteq B \iff ∀x\in A(x ∈ B)$$ and the axiom of extensionality:
 $$\forall A \forall B [\forall x (x ∈ A \iff x ∈ B) \implies A =B]$$

In the context of real analysis, $\subset$ is often written because under the Dedekind definition of the reals, $x <_{\mathbb{R}} y \iff x ⊂ y$, where $\subset$ is interpreted as the 'strict' version of $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\subset$ is ambiguous—depending on the author, it can mean one of two things:

1. **Subset:** $A \subset B$ means that $A$ is a subset of $B$.  That is, if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$.
2. **Proper Subset:** $A \subset B$ means that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.  That is, if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$, *and* there exists some $y \in B$ such that $y \not\in A$ (in other words, $B \setminus A \ne \varnothing$).

If one uses $\subset$ to denote a subset, then one typically uses $\subsetneq$ or $\subsetneqq$ to denote a proper subset; and if one uses $\subset$ to denote a proper subset, then one typically uses $\subseteq$ or $\subseteqq$ to denote a subset.  The *least ambiguous* notation is to write

- $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteqq B$ for a subset, and
- $A \subsetneq B$ or $A \subsetneqq B$ for a proper subset.

Unfortunately, different authors adopt different conventions, hence context is required in order to understand the convention used by a particular author.  Answering the original question, *either* statement is a correct definition of set equivalence in an appropriate context (i.e. depending on the convention of the author).